# Better way to get user progress?

Tags: usability, website-design, interaction-design, user-behavior

Basically, Users do "tasks" which the website gives them, they perform them outside the computer on pen & paper. Once they're done or didn't succeed they can move to the next "task".

I want to have a page were a user can view own's progress/performance.

To do exactly that, the naive approach would be a Button. Users can click it once they finish a task. with that info I can update a graph, so for example - a graph of how many tasks they did each day, will be updated once they go to their progress page. Or average tasks/day graph... etc.

The thing is, I don't know if users will do the action of clicking the button. Users probably care less about some side feature like this "progress tracking" which is way secondary to the tasks.

In the end, I want to present some stats for the user. I want to do it **even** without the user interaction with some button. Any suggestions?

Comment: You want your website to know whether or not user has done a task on pen & paper but you want the website to know about task completion without users interacting with the website? Transfer of information from physical world to digital.

Comment: I'm trying to figure a way to make users interact with it.. that they will view this as a useful feature.

Comment: Your real question is, how do you incentivize users to record their progress. Obviously one way is to change the app so that the next task can't be accessed until they say they are done with the current one. Also, look into gamification.

Comment: @AndyMercer, thanks for the creative response, its refreshing to hear it. However, preventing users to access other tasks is not the goal of the service.. Basically, the progress tracking is only for the benefit of the users. But users might ignore it as it's not their main goal.

Comment: Well, just accessing the next task tells you that they've completed the previous one, right? So you could you just mark it as done then?

Comment: I mean, tracking it completely without user interaction sounds a bit silly. Obviously they're gonna need to at least press one or two buttons, but that doesn't seem like such a big deal. I have a software reference in mind, but I'll have to share it later today when I'm home.

Comment: @AndyMercer Unfortunately not so.. As its possible that a user didn't succeed to solve the previous task. And in fact, there is no a certain order they need to do the tasks in.

Comment: Then the only thing I can think of is to incentivize the user to click a Completed button somehow. You can't really track a pen/paper task with no user interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so what I was thinking of was a tax return software.

After each step when you press "Continue", you get a little dialog above where you're promted to choose your "reasoning" for continuing:

- Topic doesn't concern me
- Edit topic later
- Finished editing topic

(There's 5 options because the 2 above refer to the topic and the 3 below to the 'dialog', which is irrelevant in this case)

[image]
<sub>Source: SteuerSparErklärung 2020</sub>

Maybe that might be an inspiration for you. I can imagine your users would press a button and then would get asked to select an option for 'how' they continued. Either they finished the task, they didn't finish it or they ignored it completely.

You can make it optional, so only those who are interested in getting their stats recorded would participate.